# How to get client IP address in a JBoss remote EJB call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, jboss, client-server, rmi

How to get the client IP address at the server-side when a EJB StatelessBean method is invoked through RMI/IIOP after a classical JNDI lookup ?

With JBoss 6.1 I tried the method `java.rmi.server.RemoteServer#getClientHost` but it throws `java.rmi.server.ServerNotActiveException: not in a remote call`. Is there any way to get the information ?

Comment: It does? It is specified to either return a hostname or throw `ServerNotActiveException`. As JBoss Remoting doesn't use `java.rmi` I would expect it to do the latter.

Comment: You're right. Miscommunication from a colleague. I have updated the question.

Comment: Well the short answer is that you can't. You certainly can't use that method. It's for RMI/JRMP and you are using RMI/IIOP. There might be something in CORBA that will tell you but I've never seen it.

Comment: I have looked at CORBA implementation but as it is conceptually a bus, the point-to-point remote call is only a specific use case. So if the information is somewhere, the client IP address should be stored as a Context property in Request context list...

Comment: If there was anything in CORBA it would be in the [Portable Interceptor package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/omg/PortableInterceptor/package-frame.html) but again I can't see it.

Comment: A clue: why not write a client and server interceptor to pass IP address as context property ?

Comment: Exactly, as long as you're in a position to install interceptors, especially at the client. You would need to control (i.e. write) the code at both ends. I was kind of expecting there would be some endpoint identifier somewhere in the intercepted ServerRequestInfo or the IORInfo.

Comment: I am interested in an answer about this CORBA-interceptors-based option.

Answer (score 2):

Is it still embedded in the thread in JBoss 6.1?

```
    String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

and then parse from there?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks, that may be a way. It is true my question is about JBoss but my code has to be deployed on WebSphere too... so I would appreciate a more portable option.