# wildfly EJB Services: How to log clients caller information

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly

We have **many** existing EJB Services, now deployed to Wildfly. We need to monior and log clients calling information, like some EJB service is accessed at some time from some client(IP)... even for more analysis.

It looks like that the built-in subsystem (jboss:domain:undertow)  only can log JAX-RS services requests information. No any log records generated for general EJB Services. So how can I figure it out?

I dont want to write logging "hard code" for so many EJB servies one by one, there may have some subsystem/configure/plug-in to achieve this?  THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be an [Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Container+interceptors) which intercepts your ejb services. In the interceptor you can then log the needed information.

To get the IP from client i only found quite old posts:

[how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-a-jboss-remote-ejb-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395165/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-a-jboss-remote-ejb-call).

[HowToGetTheClientIpAddressInAnEJB3Interceptor](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToGetTheClientIpAddressInAnEJB3Interceptor)

Maybe there are now better ways.